# cbind: is there a way to have missing values set to NA?

Tags: r, cbind

Please forgive me if I missed an answer to such a simple question.

I want to use `cbind()` to bind two columns.  One of them is a single entry shorter in length.

Can I have R supply an `NA` for the missing value?

The documentation discusses a `deparse.level` argument but this doesn't seem to be my solution.

Further, if I may be so bold, would there also be a quick way to prepend the shorter column with `NA`'s?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
x <- c(1:5)
y <- c(4:1)
length(y) = length(x)
cbind(x,y)
     x  y
[1,] 1  4
[2,] 2  3
[3,] 3  2
[4,] 4  1
[5,] 5 NA
```

or this:

```
x <- c(4:1)
y <- c(1:5)
length(x) = length(y)
cbind(x,y)
      x y
[1,]  4 1
[2,]  3 2
[3,]  2 3
[4,]  1 4
[5,] NA 5
```

I think this will do something similar to what DWin suggested and work regardless of which vector is shorter:

```
x <- c(4:1)
y <- c(1:5)

lengths <- max(c(length(x), length(y)))
length(x) <- lengths
length(y) <- lengths
cbind(x,y)
```

The code above can also be condensed to:

```
x <- c(4:1)
y <- c(1:5)
length(x) <- length(y) <- max(c(length(x), length(y)))
cbind(x,y)
```

EDIT

Here is what I came up with to address the question:

"Further, if I may be so bold, would there also be a quick way to prepend the shorter column with NA's?"

inserted into the original post by Matt O'Brien.

```
x <- c(4:1)
y <- c(1:5)

first <- 1   # 1 means add NA to top of shorter vector
             # 0 means add NA to bottom of shorter vector

if(length(x)<length(y)) {
     if(first==1) x = c(rep(NA, length(y)-length(x)),x);y=y
     if(first==0) x = c(x,rep(NA, length(y)-length(x)));y=y
} 

if(length(y)<length(x)) {
     if(first==1) y = c(rep(NA, length(x)-length(y)),y);x=x
     if(first==0) y = c(y,rep(NA, length(x)-length(y)));x=x
} 

cbind(x,y)

#       x y
# [1,] NA 1
# [2,]  4 2
# [3,]  3 3
# [4,]  2 4
# [5,]  1 5
```

Here is a function:

```
x <- c(4:1)
y <- c(1:5)

first <- 1   # 1 means add NA to top of shorter vector
             # 0 means add NA to bottom of shorter vector

my.cbind <- function(x,y,first) {

  if(length(x)<length(y)) {
     if(first==1) x = c(rep(NA, length(y)-length(x)),x);y=y
     if(first==0) x = c(x,rep(NA, length(y)-length(x)));y=y
  } 

  if(length(y)<length(x)) {
     if(first==1) y = c(rep(NA, length(x)-length(y)),y);x=x
     if(first==0) y = c(y,rep(NA, length(x)-length(y)));x=x
  } 

  return(cbind(x,y))

}

my.cbind(x,y,first)

my.cbind(c(1:5),c(4:1),1)
my.cbind(c(1:5),c(4:1),0)
my.cbind(c(1:4),c(5:1),1)
my.cbind(c(1:4),c(5:1),0)
my.cbind(c(1:5),c(5:1),1)
my.cbind(c(1:5),c(5:1),0)
```

This version allows you to cbind two vectors of different mode:

```
x <- c(4:1)
y <- letters[1:5]

first <- 1   # 1 means add NA to top of shorter vector
             # 0 means add NA to bottom of shorter vector

my.cbind <- function(x,y,first) {

  if(length(x)<length(y)) {
     if(first==1) x = c(rep(NA, length(y)-length(x)),x);y=y
     if(first==0) x = c(x,rep(NA, length(y)-length(x)));y=y
  } 

  if(length(y)<length(x)) {
     if(first==1) y = c(rep(NA, length(x)-length(y)),y);x=x
     if(first==0) y = c(y,rep(NA, length(x)-length(y)));x=x
  } 

  x <- as.data.frame(x)
  y <- as.data.frame(y)

  return(data.frame(x,y))

}

my.cbind(x,y,first)

#    x y
# 1 NA a
# 2  4 b
# 3  3 c
# 4  2 d
# 5  1 e

my.cbind(c(1:5),letters[1:4],1)
my.cbind(c(1:5),letters[1:4],0)
my.cbind(c(1:4),letters[1:5],1)
my.cbind(c(1:4),letters[1:5],0)
my.cbind(c(1:5),letters[1:5],1)
my.cbind(c(1:5),letters[1:5],0)
```

Comment: @DWin Could you not just switch the order and use `length(x) = length(y)` if `x` was shorter?

Comment: Sure, but you ought to use a test and then perform the correct action.

Comment: @DWin Okay.  Yes, that would be best.  I can try to create a function to do that unless you do it first.

Answer (score 7):

A while back I had put together a function called `Cbind` that was meant to do this sort of thing. In its current form, it should be able to handle vectors, `data.frame`s, and matrices as the input.

For now, the function is here: https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6789277

Here is how one would use the function:

```
x <- 1:5
y <- letters[1:4]
z <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("a", "b")))
Cbind(x, y, z)
#   x    y z_a z_b
# 1 1    a   1   3
# 2 2    b   2   4
# 3 3    c  NA  NA
# 4 4    d  NA  NA
# 5 5 <NA>  NA  NA
Cbind(x, y, z, first = FALSE)
#   x    y z_a z_b
# 1 1 <NA>  NA  NA
# 2 2    a  NA  NA
# 3 3    b  NA  NA
# 4 4    c   1   3
# 5 5    d   2   4
```

The <strike>two</strike> three functions required are `padNA`, `dotnames`, and `Cbind`, which are defined as follows:

```
padNA <- function (mydata, rowsneeded, first = TRUE) {
## Pads vectors, data.frames, or matrices with NA
  temp1 = colnames(mydata)
  rowsneeded = rowsneeded - nrow(mydata)
  temp2 = setNames(
    data.frame(matrix(rep(NA, length(temp1) * rowsneeded), 
                      ncol = length(temp1))), temp1)
  if (isTRUE(first)) rbind(mydata, temp2)
  else rbind(temp2, mydata)
}

dotnames <- function(...) {
## Gets the names of the objects passed through ...
  vnames <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
  vnames <- unlist(lapply(vnames,deparse), FALSE, FALSE)
  vnames
}

Cbind <- function(..., first = TRUE) {
## cbinds vectors, data.frames, and matrices together
  Names <- dotnames(...)
  datalist <- setNames(list(...), Names)
  nrows <- max(sapply(datalist, function(x) 
    ifelse(is.null(dim(x)), length(x), nrow(x))))
  datalist <- lapply(seq_along(datalist), function(x) {
    z <- datalist[[x]]
    if (is.null(dim(z))) {
      z <- setNames(data.frame(z), Names[x])
    } else {
      if (is.null(colnames(z))) {
        colnames(z) <- paste(Names[x], sequence(ncol(z)), sep = "_")
      } else {
        colnames(z) <- paste(Names[x], colnames(z), sep = "_")
      }
    }
    padNA(z, rowsneeded = nrows, first = first)
  })
  do.call(cbind, datalist)
}
```

---

Part of the reason I stopped working on the function was that the `gdata` package already has a function called `cbindX` that handles `cbind`ing `data.frame`s and matrices with different numbers of rows. It will not work directly on vectors, so you need to convert them to `data.frame`s first.

```
library(gdata)
cbindX(data.frame(x), data.frame(y), z)
#   x    y  a  b
# 1 1    a  1  3
# 2 2    b  2  4
# 3 3    c NA NA
# 4 4    d NA NA
# 5 5 <NA> NA NA
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `cbindX` - works very well. Here is [the code](https://github.com/cran/gdata/blob/master/R/cbindX.R)