# Automatically expanding data frame with NAs values across any number of columns for missing dates

Tags: r, date, datetime, dataframe

I'm interested in expanding a data frame with missing values across any number of columns for the periods where data is missing following the data units.

## Example

The problem can be easily illustrated on with use of a simple example.

### Data

The generated data contains some time series observations and dates missing on random.

```
# Data generation

# Seed
set.seed(1)

# Size
sizeDf <- 10

# Populate data frame
dta <- data.frame(
    dates = seq(
        from = Sys.Date() - (sizeDf - 1),
        to = Sys.Date(),
        by = 1
    ),
    varA = runif(n = sizeDf),
    varB = runif(n = sizeDf),
    varC = runif(n = sizeDf)
)

# Delete rows
dta <-
    dta[-sample(1:sizeDf, replace = TRUE, size = round(sqrt(sizeDf), 0)),]
```

#### Preview

```
>> dta
        dates       varA      varB       varC
1  2016-07-28 0.26550866 0.2059746 0.93470523
2  2016-07-29 0.37212390 0.1765568 0.21214252
3  2016-07-30 0.57285336 0.6870228 0.65167377
4  2016-07-31 0.90820779 0.3841037 0.12555510
7  2016-08-03 0.94467527 0.7176185 0.01339033
8  2016-08-04 0.66079779 0.9919061 0.38238796
9  2016-08-05 0.62911404 0.3800352 0.86969085
10 2016-08-06 0.06178627 0.7774452 0.34034900
```

### Key characteristics

From the perspective of the proposed analysis, the key characteristics are:

- The date units, days in that case
- Randomly missing dates

***Missing dates***

```
seq(
    from = Sys.Date() - (sizeDf - 1),
    to = Sys.Date(),
    by = 1
)[!(seq(
    from = Sys.Date() - (sizeDf - 1),
    to = Sys.Date(),
    by = 1
) %in% dta$dates)]

"2016-08-01" "2016-08-02"
```

### Desired results

The newly created data frame should look like that:

```
>> dtaNew
        dates      varA       varB      varC
1  2016-07-28 0.3337749 0.32535215 0.8762692
2  2016-07-29 0.4763512 0.75708715 0.7789147
3  2016-07-30 0.8921983 0.20269226 0.7973088
4  2016-07-31 0.8643395 0.71112122 0.4552745
5  2016-08-01        NA         NA        NA
6  2016-08-02        NA         NA        NA
7  2016-08-03 0.9606180 0.14330438 0.6049333
8  2016-08-04 0.4346595 0.23962942 0.6547239
9  2016-08-05 0.7125147 0.05893438 0.3531973
10 2016-08-06 0.3999944 0.64228826 0.2702601
```

This simply obtained with use of:

```
dtaNew[dtaNew$dates %in% missDates, 2:4] <- NA
```

where the `missDates` is taken from the previous `seq`.

---

## Attempts

Creating vector with all the dates is simple:

```
allDates <- seq(from = min(dta$dates), to = max(dta$dates), by = 1)
```

but obviously I cannot just push it to the data frame:

```
>> dta$allDates  <- allDates
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "allDates", value = c(17010, 17011,  : 
  replacement has 10 rows, data has 8
```

The possible solution could use the loop that would push the row with `NA` values to the data frame row by row for each of the dates identified as missing but this is grossly inefficient and messy.

---

To sum up, I'm interested in achieving the following:

1. Expanding the data frame with all the dates following the same unit. I.e. for missing daily data days are added, for missing quarterly data quarters are added.
2. I would like to then push the NA values across all the columns in the data frame for where the missing date was found

Comment: If there are no repeated dates you can use `merge`.

Comment: You are trying to column bind two dataframes with variable row numbers, which is why it fails. Try the solutions mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074163/cbind-is-there-a-way-to-have-missing-values-set-to-na

Comment: Also suggest you clear the verbose description, took me a long time to understand what you were speaking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can use `rbind.fill` from the `plyr` package to get your desired output:

```
sizeDf <- 10
# Populate data frame
dta <- data.frame(
  dates = seq(
    from = Sys.Date() - (sizeDf - 1),
    to = Sys.Date(),
    by = 1
  ),
  varA = runif(n = sizeDf),
  varB = runif(n = sizeDf),
  varC = runif(n = sizeDf)
)

# Delete rows
dta <-dta[-sample(1:sizeDf, replace = TRUE, size = round(sqrt(sizeDf), 0)),]

#Get missing dates
missing_dates <- seq(from=min(dta$dates), to=max(dta$dates), by=1)[!(seq(from=min(dta$dates), to=max(dta$dates), by=1) %in% dta$dates)]

#Create the new dataset by using plyr's rbind.fill function
dta_new <- plyr::rbind.fill(dta,data.frame(dates=missing_dates))

#Order the data by the dates column
dta_new <- dta_new[order(dta_new$dates),]

#Print it
print(dta_new, row.names = F, right = F)


 dates      varA        varB      varC      
 2016-07-28 0.837859418 0.2966637 0.61245244
 2016-07-29 0.144884547 0.9284294 0.11033990
 2016-07-30          NA        NA         NA
 2016-07-31          NA        NA         NA
 2016-08-01 0.003167049 0.9096805 0.29239470
 2016-08-02 0.574859760 0.1466993 0.69541969
 2016-08-03          NA        NA         NA
 2016-08-04 0.748639215 0.9602836 0.67681826
 2016-08-05 0.983939562 0.4867804 0.35270309
 2016-08-06 0.383366957 0.2241982 0.09244522
```

I hope this helps.