# Loop over multiple data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I've got 4 data frame with this structure:

data1:

```
1.8064 2.2016 2.4506 2.1828 2.1171 1.9308 2.1707 2.1885
2.2310 2.2400 1.9115 2.1527 2.0934 1.7989 2.2144 2.0091
1.9248 2.2038 1.9676 1.9224 1.9502 1.7990 2.0824 2.1300
2.0095 2.0341 1.8433 1.8361 1.9958 1.8243 2.0397 2.0482
2.1143 2.2627 1.7620 1.7561 1.9490 1.9803 1.9336 2.2511
2.2377 2.5414 1.7867 1.6618 2.5090 1.8325 2.0212 2.1616
2.3476 2.1878 2.0469 1.7508 2.2969 1.7939 2.0291 2.0721
2.3534 2.0932 2.3502 1.9960 2.0710 1.9923 1.7787 1.9772
2.2607 2.1504 2.3685 2.1148 2.1961 1.7738 1.8405 2.0135
2.2411 1.9916 2.4726 2.0347 2.0751 1.7570 1.8874 1.9385
```

data2:

```
2.1913 1.8981 2.2441 2.3068 2.1198 2.1484 1.8056 1.7747
2.0842 1.8750 2.3023 2.1204 1.8972 2.1534 1.8028 1.9401
2.2105 1.9618 2.2472 1.9656 2.3098 1.9771 1.9520 1.8627
2.2863 1.9959 2.1781 1.9544 1.9281 1.9286 1.9699 2.0330
2.1987 2.0583 2.0953 2.0206 2.1148 2.3789 1.7052 1.9145
2.0513 2.0850 1.9810 2.4943 1.9120 2.2209 1.9461 2.0882
2.0049 2.0416 1.9303 2.3681 1.8974 2.0054 1.9261 1.9097
1.6882 2.1196 1.8641 2.3600 2.0931 1.7641 2.1131 1.7748
1.8840 1.7604 1.7664 2.2000 2.0055 1.8229 1.9871 1.9168
1.7340 1.9656 1.8480 2.0523 1.9950 1.8716 1.9206 1.7786
1.9604 1.9804 1.9601 2.0599 1.8969 1.8087 2.1845 1.8598
```

data3:

```
1.8064 2.2016 2.4506 2.1828 2.1171 1.9308 2.1707 2.1885
2.2310 2.2400 1.9115 2.1527 2.0934 1.7989 2.2144 2.0091
1.9248 2.2038 1.9676 1.9224 1.9502 1.7990 2.0824 2.1300
2.0095 2.0341 1.8433 1.8361 1.9958 1.8243 2.0397 2.0482
2.1143 2.2627 1.7620 1.7561 1.9490 1.9803 1.9336 2.2511
2.2377 2.5414 1.7867 1.6618 2.5090 1.8325 2.0212 2.1616
2.3476 2.1878 2.0469 1.7508 2.2969 1.7939 2.0291 2.0721
2.3534 2.0932 2.3502 1.9960 2.0710 1.9923 1.7787 1.9772
2.2607 2.1504 2.3685 2.1148 2.1961 1.7738 1.8405 2.0135
2.2411 1.9916 2.4726 2.0347 2.0751 1.7570 1.8874 1.9385
```

data4:

```
2.1913 1.8981 2.2441 2.3068 2.1198 2.1484 1.8056 1.7747
2.0842 1.8750 2.3023 2.1204 1.8972 2.1534 1.8028 1.9401
2.2105 1.9618 2.2472 1.9656 2.3098 1.9771 1.9520 1.8627
2.2863 1.9959 2.1781 1.9544 1.9281 1.9286 1.9699 2.0330
2.1987 2.0583 2.0953 2.0206 2.1148 2.3789 1.7052 1.9145
2.0513 2.0850 1.9810 2.4943 1.9120 2.2209 1.9461 2.0882
2.0049 2.0416 1.9303 2.3681 1.8974 2.0054 1.9261 1.9097
1.6882 2.1196 1.8641 2.3600 2.0931 1.7641 2.1131 1.7748
1.8840 1.7604 1.7664 2.2000 2.0055 1.8229 1.9871 1.9168
1.7340 1.9656 1.8480 2.0523 1.9950 1.8716 1.9206 1.7786
1.9604 1.9804 1.9601 2.0599 1.8969 1.8087 2.1845 1.8598
```

I need to get column 1 from data1, column 1 from data2, column 1 from data3 and column 1 from data4 and combine them into a single data frame, side by side and do the same with the other columns.

I was using this method, but it is a little bit rudimentary

```
dat1 <- data.frame(data1$V1)
dat2 <- data.frame(data2$V1)
dat3 <- data.frame(data3$V1)
dat4 <- data.frame(data4$V1)

final_data1 <- cbind(dat1,dat2,dat3,dat4)
. 
.
.


dat1 <- data.frame(data1$V8)
dat2 <- data.frame(data2$V8)
dat3 <- data.frame(data3$V8)
dat4 <- data.frame(data4$V8)

final_data8 <- cbind(dat1,dat2,dat3,dat4)
```

Is there any way to do this with a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through columns, bind them, and keep the resulting 8 dataframes in a list:

```
res <- lapply(1:8, function(i){ cbind(data1[i], data2[i], data3[i], data4[i]) })
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but how I can extract the 8 dataframe created from that list? I would use them to make histograms.

Comment: @Enrique `res[[1]]` should give you the first data.frame.

Comment: Another question. If I want to join four data frame but each one has got different size. How I can join them with your method? I mean for example: dat1 with 100 objects, dat2 with 50 objects etc...

Comment: @Enrique [see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074163) for *cbind*ing unequal data.frames.

Answer (score 1):

We can place all the data in a `list`, extract the first column and `cbind` it together.

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(mget(paste0("data", 1:4)), `[`, 1))
```

It may be better to keep it in a single dataset with an id col to refer to which dataset it came from

```
library(data.table)
dt <- rbindlist(mget(paste0("data", 1:4)), idcol = TRUE)
```

Also, for plotting purpose, it may be better to keep in the 'long' format

```
dL <- melt(dt, id.var = ".id")
```

and use `ggplot` to plot

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dL, aes(value, ..density.., colour = variable)) +
                       geom_freqpoly()
```

Or use `geom_histogram` with `facet_wrap` (for individual plots for each column)

```
ggplot(dL, aes(value)) +
        geom_histogram() +
        facet_wrap(~variable)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use an `eval(parse())` construction:

```
df1 = data.frame(V1 = 1:10)
df2 = data.frame(V1 = 1:10)
df3 = data.frame(V1 = 1:10)
df4 = data.frame(V1 = 1:10)

final = matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(df1), ncol = 4)

for (i in 1:4) {
  final[, i] = eval(parse(text = paste0('df', i, '$V1')))
}
```

Another way is to put all dfs in a list and use lapply:

```
dfList = list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
do.call(cbind, lapply(dfList, `[[`, 'V1'))
```

Above, the `lapply` loops over all dataframes and returns a list where each elemnt is the first column. the part `do.call(cbind, ...)` then binds all those elements together into one matrix.